# How to fix success problem while getting data from php to javascript file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have used before these jquery-ajax and php codes. Everything was fine but know there is a problem that success function not working. However, php codes are working, I can add data to mysql database, but I couldn't post info back to javascript file again by use "echo" or any way. Is this problem could originate because of server? I need your support.

I have checked php file is working or not and there was no problem about php. In javascript file in ajax codes, I have tried beforeSend and complete functions, everything were fine. But success function not working.

JS codes:

```
var userCookie = 1;
    var question_txt = document.getElementById("question_txt").value;
    var category_slct = document.getElementById("category_slct").value;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: websitePHP + "ask.php",
        data: {
            user : userCookie,
            quest : question_txt,
            cat : category_slct
        },

        beforeSend: function(){ 

        },
        success: function(data){
            alert(data); 
            if(data == 'ok'){
                alert('Question added');
            }
        }
    })
```

PHP codes:

```
include("ayar.php");

$userID = $_POST['user']; 
$categoryID = $_POST['cat'];
$question_txt = $_POST['quest']; 
$askedTime = time();

$addQuestion = $vt->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$QUESTIONS." (userID, categoryID, question, image, link, sight, pinned, bestAnswerID, askedTime, publishedTime, published) 
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"); 
$addQuestion->execute(array(''.$userID.'',''.$categoryID.'', ''.$question_txt.'', '', '', 0, 0, '', ''.$askedTime.'', '', 0));  

echo 'ok';

exit();
```

I need to get back response from php to js by success function in ajax.

Thanks for your help,
Best regards.

Comment: Send data in `JSON` and then parse that json in your js file

Comment: _Side note:_ There's no need to concatenate the variables when putting them in an array. Just do: `array($var1, $var2, $var3, ...)`, or even better yet, use the short array syntax: `[$var1, $var2, $var3, ...]`

Comment: I have tried json_encode in php and dataType: 'json' in ajax. Normally when I forexample type _echo 'ok'_ ajax have to get 'ok' in js. I dont understand where is problem

Comment: Go check what the browser console has to say, go check how exactly the request gets answered in the dev tools network panel.

Comment: Is your ajax sending data to php file?

Comment: yes it send data, php can add my data to mysql database, but I cannot get return (php to js)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try 
return 'ok'; instead of echo 'ok'; and removing exit(); function